# jQuery hover() and the hover-state should be kept

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm new to jQuery and I try something like this:

```
   <ul id="CatNavi">
  <li class="CatLevel1 SubMenue">Top Level 1
    <div class="sub">
      <ul>
         <li class="CatLevel2">Sub Level 1</li>
         <li class="CatLevel2">Sub Level 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the jquery looks like this:

```
   $(function() { 
 $("li.CatLevel1 a").hover(function() {
   $(this).next("div.sub").slideDown(500);
 },function() {
  $(this).next("div.sub").slideUp(200);
 });
});
```

It works fine. When I hover the Top Level 1 the div class="sub" is shown but I can't click the elements in this div because the hover state disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Greetz
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should look like this:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#CatNavi li.CatLevel1").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("div.sub").slideDown(500);
  },function() {
    $(this).children("div.sub").slideUp(200);
  });
});
```

When you move off the `<a>` the `mouseleave` event fires...which is what the second handler in that [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler is, hiding the siblings.  `mouseleave` *doesn't* fire when entering a child, so having the hover events on the `<li>` instead means they won't fire when you enter the child `<div>`/`<ul>` elements.

Comment: This also doesn't work. Now the <div class="sub"> slides up and down when I'm with the mouse on it.

Comment: @Ron - That shouldn't be the case at all, not if it's a child, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/K8HF8/ Do you have a link to your problem page?

Comment: @Nick here ist the link to the problem page: http://seo.web-kiste.com/. User and pass are: testshop

Comment: @Ron - Ahhh, you're adding some spacing there with the `top` offset of the children, so you *are* leaving the parent.  Either add a `.stop()` in before the `.slide...()` calls, or use the hoverIntent plugin here: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: @Nick Even with a .stop() it slides up and down. The additionally hoverIntent file would cause one more request and i try to keep the requests as small as possible. Is there any possibility to fix it 'cause you mentioned something "adding some spaces"?

Comment: @Ron - You could set a timeout...but then you're doing what the hoverIntent plugin's doing.  Take a different approach here, just combine your scripts into a single `.js` (minified as well).  You have to do timers of some sort because you have a gap area where you're on neither the parent or the child.  If you changed your CSS to where the `<div>` didn't have a gap between the top of it and the bottom of the `<li>` parent that would eliminate it as well...a few ways to tackle this.

Comment: @Nick - Now I've changed the CSS from top: to padding-top: and made the background-image transparent for the gap. All works very fine but now it's hardly possible to click on the link from li.CatLevel1 a.

Comment: @Ron - It has hardly any size in the page, make sure to give it some dimensions, possibly a `display: inline-block;` as well.

Comment: @Nick - Now it's working perfect. The problem with the TopLevel link was the overlaying background-image from <div class="sub">. I've changed the z-index from 20 to -20 and it works. Many many thanks for your professional help and giving me some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Change the hover to work on the `<li>` not `<a>` link. This means the cursor is still on top of the `<li>` while you click on the link in the submenu. That way the second hover function only fires when you completely move off the list element, which the submenu is inside.

```
$("li.CatLevel1").hover( /* hover code here */ )
```

I'm assuming the above HTML is wrong and you mean hovering over the 'Top Level 1', which should be a link for the hover function to kick in in the jQuery.

Comment: With $("li.CatLevel1") the hover-Event doesn't work. What should be wrong with the HTML-Code?